# How do I play with my dog after her teeth get removed

Tags: dogs, play, toys, dental-care

My 9 year old Pomeranium/Shih Tzu mix is getting her teeth removed soon, she's not particularly old and is still very hyperactive and loves to play and run around. But all of her favourite games involve chewing things or playing tug-of-war or chasing balls. Will she still be able to play all those games after the operation? And if not, can anyone recommend any games that we can play instead?

I've done some research, but the only recommendations that I've been able to find have been toys that she can play with by herself, like puzzle toys and toys that move around themselves.

I'm looking for a way that we can play *with* her, because she loses interest if we aren't involved. She'll actually pick up her toy and push it against us until we give in and either throw it or play tug, the idea of her doing that and me not being able to play with her honestly breaks my heart a little bit.

Comment: Once she heals she'll still be able to play some of these, but won't have as strong a grasp, but that won't stop her from enjoying herself. Ask the vet how long to wait before any gum rough housing.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, she will be able to play her favorite games, but not exactly in the same intensity as before.

Keep in mind that before dentures were invented, our grannies didn't starve to death either. They chewed with their gums instead of their teeth, which works relatively well.

Her gums will take a while to harden, but she will still be able to chew and tug toys without any teeth. Very hard or strongly structured toys might hurt her, though. If that is the case, she'll stop playing with them on her own. If she still plays with toys, they obviously don't hurt her (too much). Let her decide for herself which toys are still acceptable.

As to alternatives, please have a look at this collection of ideas: [Alternatives to walking a dog](https://pets.stackexchange.com/q/23521/12501)