# Hound/Retriever keeps escaping

Tags: dogs, behavior, training, psychology, containment

I have a mix of Hound and Retriever who just wont stop escaping. Here is the story:

We got her from a rescue shelter about 3 years ago, and she was the only one that was laying down and kept quiet, so we decided to get her, thinking she would be easy to take care of. However, we kind of thought wrong, and she chewed up just about every piece of paper in our house. We solved that by getting chew toys. However, we haven't solved the problem of her seeing a squirrel and deciding to jump a 6 foot tall privacy fence. We tried a tether with concrete (she has pulled the concrete blocks and almost hung herself on the fence), we tried tether in the ground (it sort of works, but we have to check it now and again). I don't want to use the "stubborn dog" collar because it just seems so wrong mentally for my dog. Is there any way I can train her to stay in the yard?

Side note: We also have a lake that after escaping, she goes to and jumps in the mud.

Comment: P.S: I cant get the name of the shelter at this moment.

Comment: Please NEVER tie your dog up outside alone.

Comment: Ik Im out there with her, In fact either me, my mother, or my father are out there with her

Comment: But its just the fact that I want her to be able to let her run around free in our back yard, because we have a huge backyard.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Your dog needs mental and physical stimulation!

The question should not be, "how can I physically trap and contain my dog?", rather, "why is my dog doing this, and how can it be corrected?".

> she chewed up just about every piece of paper in our house. We solved that by getting chew toys.

No. Incorrect. By just buying chew toys, you haven't "solved" anything.

*You need to play with those toys with your dog (fetch, tug of war, hide and seek, etc.).*

Since your dog can't engage themself, that's where you as their owner must come in and help your dog.

**Every dog needs physical and mental exercise and stimulation, when neglected in these areas, bad behavior such as "chewing up every piece of paper in our house" will surface.**

For physical exercise, play with your dog in your yard, go on walks, run around, and have dog playdates.

[rover.com](https://www.rover.com/blog/how-long-should-i-walk-my-dog-each-day/) says:

> In general, most dogs benefit from between 30 minutes to two hours of physical activity per day, according to PetMD. That can be all at once, but most people break it up into two or three walks per day. There’s no perfect formula to determine how long to walk your dog, but half an hour at a time is a good rule of thumb. Start with a gentle 30-minute walk in the morning, and another before dinner.
>
> There’s really no limit to how far you walk your dog as long as they’re comfortable. For some dogs, that’s around the block. For others, it’s ten miles. Just remember to build distance and stamina gradually over time.

For mental stimulation, play games like hide and seek, practice tricks, and give your dog a challenge, like putting your dog's food in an egg carton. See https://www.puppyleaks.com/more-mental-stimulation/.

I am almost 100% confident that your dog needs more mental and physical stimulation, also because you say this:

> We also have a lake that after escaping, she goes to and jumps in the mud.

See - she wants to play!

> Is there any way I can train her to stay in the yard?

You can:
a) follow my advice to physically and mentally stimulate your dog;
b) watch your dog more often;
c) remove climbing aids and add landscaping.

Although I would recommend all three.

I added option c) because it will reduce escape attempts, but, **ideally, you want to treat the cause, not the symptom.**

You can find more information [here](https://www.akc.org/expert-advice/home-living/how-to-keep-a-dog-from-escaping-the-yard/).

Answer (score 6):

I can only agree with [Nai54's answer](https://pets.stackexchange.com/a/31256/12501). If your dog escapes your yard, it doesn't mean that the dog is bad, it means that the yard doesn't fulfill the dog's needs.

A very easy way to entertain a dog is a **puzzle feeder**. Those come in various shapes and sizes and can also be crafted by you. Feeding a dog in a bowl is easy and boring, but feeding them in a puzzle feeder adds a little mental stimulation to the process without requiring more time from you. If this is done in the morning, the dog is a little more relaxed and balanced throughout the day.

Since she likes to chew things, you could redirect this destructive behavior into a safe direction with a **food dispenser** toy like a Kong or similar product. There are many different fillings (from soft and easy to lick out to dry or frozen to withstand the attempts at getting it out).

Please see [this post](https://pets.stackexchange.com/q/23521/12501) for a list of more ideas and examples of games to play.

And don't forget to take the dog on **walks**. It would probably be ideal if you had a dog park nearby where dogs can run around and play with each other. If you don't - she loves the lake, so why not take her to the lake on a long leash and let her have fun? If you offer her the things she likes, she may feel less of a need to escape.

As with the puzzle feeder, it's ideal to take one walk in the morning / before noon. It doesn't even have to be extremely long, just 20 - 30 minutes is enough. That relaxes your dog for several hours. You can take a second or even third walk later in the day, or play games like fetch or frisbee with your dog instead of a walk. With some training, you can teach your dog to drop the frisbees or balls she catches near you so you don't have to run around the whole yard.

Comment: IK that however our backyard is half the size of the football field. She has plenty of room to run, but she just doesnt stay in the yard so we have to keep her on a tether.

Comment: The size of the yard doesn't matter at all. If there's no entertainment in the yard, your dog will try to escape the yard. And please keep in mind that keeping a dog on tether can lead to behavioral and cognitive problems (that's why it was **outlawed** in several countries around the world).

Comment: Plus every toy we get her, whether its indestroyable, she will still destroy it.

Comment: So I dont know how to keep her happy.

Comment: @JosephCasey Toys alone won't make your dog happy. Interaction with people and dogs would make her happy. If you play fetch with her, she's much happier than if you just give her the ball to destroy. If she doesn't give the ball back, you can throw little treat in the yard near her and let her search for them. Or find other games you can play together.

Comment: @RemodMonica if she has no reason to stay, she will not stay. The reason should be an environment where she assume that she would miss something, while outside. So it need to be entertaining to stay in the yard, and she need to feel a strong bond to the pack. Packs play WITH EACH OTHER, they run together, hunt together, follow tracks together and so on THE WHOLE DAY LONG.To have some episodes of around 20-30 minutes is much less exhausting than that :D Show her, that she is a member of your pack and she will stay.