# Help with a rescue

Tags: dogs, behavior, adoption, exercise

We got our rescue three days ago. We met him on summer, spent a week together, he was stray. He was rescued and a shelter/rescue agreed to keep him for us until we solved our living arrangements to accommodate him (he is a Tornjak). Initially we were told he was aprox one year old, the vet determined he is now approximately 10 months old. We have a female, 14 yo JRT. They get along ok, considering the circumstances and so on.
The current situation is as follows- for several reasons the rescue/shelter made us take him in already, we are leaving in a small flat/apartment. He is a country dog, we live in the city. We have been giving him walks but he is getting used to the noises, people, cars, so have not had him outside for prolonged periods as not to overstimulate him (he gets nervous and stops listening) or that’s my intake now.
He is a very sensitive, peaceful,  dog, nothing like our JRT at his age. We have been solving issues as they arise (like marking territory and so on). Today he started barking at noises on the street, at one time my JRT urinated herself on the bed. I have addressed this peacefully and rewarding calm behavior.

As for the rest, he sleeps well (he was eventually placed in a crate at night in the rescue once it was too cold for him to be outside).

Leaving aside that the rescue basically put us against the wall to take him under these circumstances and so on, when he would have been better once we get our house with the garden and all, I am at a loss.

He is a sweet dog, he still thinks he is the size of a Chihuahua , and in general terms is adapting to our dynamics and rules. Now, I know he would benefit from more outside time but I do feel we need to take it slowly while he remains scared or gets overwhelmed. I am afraid that he is underexercised or stressed by being locked in a flat (he is not pacing, no destructive or unwanted behavior beyond the now barking at noises and things) but I also don’t think he is ready for full immersion in a dog park or crowded areas with more dogs when he still does not respond well to us and is hard to keep him under control (40kg).

I would hate to have to send him back and I don’t know how to proceed.

Lastly, he hasn’t been neutered yet due to his age.

Thank you for your time, any feedback will be welcomed.

Comment: This site helps you most, if you ask specific questions. It is not a forum. We answer questions :) So please ask a question or tell us, what is the aim you want to reach. So you would get helpfull answers. As I see it now, you search for alternatives to walk your dog, because walking is stressfull until it adapted fully. Have a look here: https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/23521/alternatives-to-walking-a-dog

Comment: I tried my best to provide context and lost the point. So I am aware he needs more outside time because of his history and breed, but I am prioritizing positive short walks 15-20 mins at a time so he doesn’t get overwhelmed/ overstimulated because then he doesn’t listen, respond and the outside time is not positive either. Is this approach ok? Any better advice? Thank you

Comment: great question! Please use the "edit" in the bottom of your original post to add it there :) For me your strategy sounds good. But there are people here with more dog-experience than me. Does the linked question helps you to compensate the energy of your dog?