# Help! My dogs are bored >.<

Tags: dogs, behavior, training, chewing

So my dogs are super spoiled. They literally had everything they wanted growing up. Got a new stuffed animal like every week till they got bored with them after a year or two. Used to go crazy for those giant smoked femur bones till they got bored with those too. I still get them various treats and rawhide rolls so they never run out. They have a couple of those puzzle treat balls that they have to roll around to get the treats out. I've never really walked them very much, but they have an enormous yard and a doggy door and can go in and out as they please. But now they just started stealing random stuff..... Took a box of tissues outside and ripped it apart. Stole a fiberglass repair kit I had on the counter. Thankfully didn't break and eat any of the tubes, or probably would've gotten sick. Stole and chewed up my bf's paintball gun.
What is their problem? :| ..... They get all the pets and attentions they want. I work from home, so it's not like they're lonely.
And used to steal stuff only when I would go out for longer than like 5-6 hrs, but now they started doing it at night too.

Edit:
In regard to suggestions in the other post, my dogs don't want to play ball or frisby with me. Never have. They only play with each other. And even at the dog park they just wander around for half hour and ignore other dogs trying to play with them, then just sit by me the rest of the time. I have tried getting them interactive puzzle feeders but they only play with them for so long before they lose interest, even if there are still treats inside. I doubt they would like a treadmill since they have a whole 3000 sq ft yard to play in. And they don't dig. At least not in the yards and not the couple of times I took them to the beach. So I don't think they would care for a sand box either.

Comment: Please have a look into this question and let us know, if (and why) it does not help you: [alternatives to walk a dog](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/23521/alternatives-to-walking-a-dog)

Comment: "What is their problem? :| ..... They get all the pets and attentions they want." Well, no, they don't. As a kid, did you ever go outside to play on your own? Or only if you could meet a friend to play together? Chewing on plushies or bones is only entertaining for so long, but it doesn't really burn all that excess energy. And dogs are very social animals. They want to interact with you, play with you, walk with you. Just pets alone won't entertain them. Have a look at the linked question and try playing some games with them. Just 10 minutes twice a day should improve their behavior.

Comment: @elmy well yeah, I went and rode my bike all over the place by myself, or went on a swing or played in the dirt or climbed trees or something lol
And there's no reason closing the question. I got two of them so they keep each other company. And they very much don't care about playing ball with me or chasing a frisby. They only play with each other, even at the dog park they show very little interest in socializing.

Comment: @Raksha closing the question is in no way an attack or citique on your question, I just did it because your question would get the same answers as an existing question. That's how the StackExchange network works. And I'd say you were an exception as a kid. If my friends weren't there, I'd rather spend my time in front of the TV or PC. Maybe you could play tug of war with both of them or engage them in a different group game that doesn't involve chasing after a toy. I've had much success playing the hat game with my dog.

Comment: In my opinion the difference here is that humans have a level of imagination dogs (very probable) do not have. If a child plays alone, it can be a pirate, princess, wolf, butterfly and what ever it can imagine. A dog will stay a dog while playing. And so a dog is limited in "own ideas" how to use things. But if a human interacts with the dog, then there would be more variability in non-living-things and their usage. Some kind of dish starts to fly, some plushy thing starts to smell very different, there are treats where never been some before and so on. This can one dog not do for another.

Comment: Natural behavior of dogs would include sniffing, and following some kind of route to find animals, running and coordinate with the other dogs to hunt this animal down. Maybe digging to make a nest for the puppies, or to hide some leftovers of the food. So this behaviors are typical for "entertaining" dog aktivities. Could be your dogs have different interests, but they have no need to hunt, dig or similar. And so, yes they are bored. Like humans do not need to sew their own clothes, seed/hunt their own food and build their own houses anymore. But humans will find their own alternatives.

Comment: And to be honest: your dogs found their own alternative too: steeling ;) So it is your task to find an alternative action for them which fits more your imagination of a GOOD activity :) (and as big as your garden my be: it stays the same, year after year. No animals to hunt, no new activities, no food one could search for...)

Comment: Maybe you can try some of the linked activities and then come back with a more detailed question. Like "My dogs do not like ball games, hunting games [...] how can I interest them for balls?" Or "What other dog games are there beneath the linked ones?" or "What dog games fit for two dogs and one human?"

Comment: That they decided to find their own objects of interest (what you  called stealing) means that mental stimulation is probably the way to go. And by that I don’t mean another  puzzle toy, but taking 1:1 time with them and e.g. teaching them a trick or two. If your dogs truly don’t want to interact with you at all, you have possibly a bigger problem than you realize.