# Can horses eat yoghurt?

Tags: health, diet, horses, supplements

I've been browsing probiotic solutions for horses. I was wondering if it's safe for horses to eat yoghurt with live cultures

Related: [Can dogs eat yoghurt?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/21235/can-dogs-eat-yoghurt)