# Is it normal for a long haired doxie to like yogurt?

Tags: dogs, diet, safety, junior-pets

My 9 month old puppy loves yogurt and I don't know if that's normal or not. Is it normal for a long haired doxie (Dachshund) to like yogurt?

Comment: Please see this https://pets.stackexchange.com/q/21235 it's about whether it is safe for dogs to eat yogurt, in short yogurt in itself is safe but it sometimes contains additives which could be toxic to dogs, for example xylitol - an artificial sweetener - is extremely toxic to dogs. And also I assume "doxie" is a slang for Dachshund so I added that to main body of your question. And yes it's normal, many dogs like yogurt but you should always carefully read the labels and make sure it's without any toxic additives.

Comment: I see that you attempted to edit the existing question that I linked for you, that's not what the purpose of suggested edits is, the purpose of them is to fix typos and style without change in post essence, the person in the linked question asked about her own dog not about your dog.

Comment: stop messing with my posts lila

Comment: its not your account lila

Comment: @LILYKURCZEWSKI: your tone is not very nice. lila just tried to explain you the rules of the site. To avoid other misunderstandings in the future, you should read those rules - you can find them clicking on the "?" pictogram on the upper-right corner of the page.

Comment: Please note that all contributions here, including your posts, are licensed under Creative Commons, and this site is collaboratively edited, like Wikipedia. All we want to do is to help you, and to get good answers it is really important that your questions are marked with all the relevant tags, contain proper punctuation and clearly specify the problem. It is also important because the Q&A are not to help just you; they also have to be useful to all the other future readers who would happen to have the same problem. If you are not comfortable with the idea of your contributions ...

Comment: ...being collaboratively edited by other trusted users, this may not be the site for you. Also, please note that unfriendly and unkind language is not welcome here.

Answer (score 1):

@lila provided already a nice comment on the safety of eating yogurt.

I will tell you about our experiences. We had one half Pekingese in the past, and another more-or-less Pekingese currently (we = my parents). The story is the same with both of them.

My mother (their main caretaker) discovered that they like yogurt. For a few times, she provided them with readily bought yogurt, the dogs could not be happier. Occasionally they wanted more.

Which led my mother to the idea to make the "yogurt" in the house. They bought milk, and then the milk was intentionally "forgotten" at room temperature after being exposed briefly to room air. Overnight, the milk transformed into a yogurt-ish food. Which the dogs enjoyed equally. No food additives, no limited quantity, no breaking the bank for buying specialized products, everybody happy.

Notes:

- the bought milk is industrially processed in the same factories where yogurt is made, so it might have additives as well;
- there are claims that the adults of any species should not consume any milk or dairy products, for health reasons.

---

Bottom line: it is not out of the ordinary for a dog to like yogurt.

Comment: thank you my dog gets a spoonful of plain yogurt a day and goat milk in the afternoon if you want to try giving your dog goat milk go to small guys farm supplies  its good for all animals and steve warms up to you as soon as you come in the door (steve is a cat not a person)

Comment: I would warm up too if I would have a chance to get a cup of goat milk, too ( I am a person, not a cat :D )

Comment: do not drink it, it will make you sick and probably die.

Comment: steve died today of lung cancer. :(

Comment: @LILYKURCZEWSKI: I am sorry, both for steve, and for your sorrow. I wish you recover soon after the loss.